# find all simple representations of the following quiver

Tags: representation-theory

The quiver in question is a relatively simple one:

[image]

How would one go about finding all of the simple representations of this quiver?

Answer (score 1):

The quiver has no directed loops, so the simple representations should just be the three one dimensional representations concentrated on each vertex.